# 'downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()` to obtain a current download URL.?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
Storage.storage().reference().child(ImageUid).putData(ImageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Couldn't Upload Image")
            } else {
                print("Uploaded")
                let downloadURl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                if let url = downloadURl {
                    self.SetUpUser(Image: url)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error:

> 'downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use
>   `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()` to obtain a current
>   download URL.

How do I fix this?

Comment: And you are using a external library I guess? Do you mind telling which one?

Comment: using google firebase and accessing photo library for app building

Comment: @larme shown extension below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says that you need to use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()` well you need to use it:

```
let storageItem = Storage.storage().reference().child(ImageUid)
storageItem.putData(ImageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Couldn't Upload Image")
    } else {
        print("Uploaded")
        storageItem.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            if url != nil {
                self.SetUpUser(Image: url!.absoluteString)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: error: "Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'String'" -  didn't work

Comment: @WahajUddin Your function accept a string and the value is url. You need to use `absoluteString`. I edited my answer.

Comment: @WahajUddin Your welcome. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this site don't know how to :/

Comment: @WahajUddin no problem. You can check this: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: didn't work so I've posted the extension so you can view the the whole detail below

Comment: Dear @WahajUddin Your question was **'downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()` to obtain a current download URL.?** Is only a question by post. Your code failed before execute my code **storageItem.downloadURL**. Your new problem need a new question. You need to see why your image won't upload.

Comment: Yeah sorry being such a noob I figured it out thank you - it was because I hadn't allowed access to storage in firebase