# No recognition of StorageMetadata // Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

Tags: swift, firebase, metadata

I get the Error message **Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'** after Updating my Firebase Project. I changed none of the code through the last days and randomly its not working anymore.
The same Error appears in 3 different spots:

1:

```
// Referencing Firebase storage child with the unique identifier, and updating with the image from the picker
        DatabaseManager.shared.REF_POSTS_IMAGES.child(imgUid).putData(imgData, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to upload image Firebase storage")
            } else {
                print("Successfully uploaded image to Firebase storage")
                let downloadUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                if let url = downloadUrl {
                    //once the image is uploaded to firebase stoarge, its then posted to the database
                    self.postToFirebase(imgUrl: url)
                }
            }
        })
```

2:

```
func uploadImages(_ data:Data,userid:String){

    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    let imagesRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("photoPosts")
    let childs = imagesRef.child(userid)
    var imgUrl = NSURL()

    childs.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
        imgUrl = (metadata?.downloadURL())! as NSURL

        self.updateURL(userid: userid, user_URL: imgUrl)
    }
}
```

3:

```
func save() {
    let newPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()
    let newPostKey = newPostRef.key

    // 1. save image
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(newPostKey)")

        storage.putData(imageData).observe(.success, handler: { (snapshot) in
            self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            let postDictionary = [
                "imageDownloadURL" : self.downloadURL,
                "caption" : self.caption
            ]
            newPostRef.setValue(postDictionary)
        })
    }
}
```

The answers from other Posts don't help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['downloadURL()' is deprecated: Use \`StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()\` to obtain a current download URL.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005963/downloadurl-is-deprecated-use-storagereference-downloadurlwithcompletion)

Comment: No, this post didn't helped me...

Comment: The documentation says it exists : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata but obviously it is not present in the latest Firebase version.

Comment: Found this https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#5.0.0 In the changes it is stated "Removed downloadURLs property on StorageMetadata. Use StorageReference.downloadURL(completion:) to obtain a current download URL."

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281266/metadata-downloadurl-not-recognized-anymore/50281311

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the changes in swift 5.0, metadata no longer has a method of downloadURL.

Instead you must do something along the lines of:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(fileName)
    storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download url:", error!)
        return
    } else {
       //Do something with url
      }

  })
})
```

Hope this helps. You can also take a look at: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798766/firebase-storage-downloadurl-is-deprecated-use-storagereference-downloadurl) answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007881/image-url-in-firebasestorage-does-not-exist-responseerrordomain-com-google-htt/52028008#52028008) answer, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281266/%E2%80%A6) answer or just look at the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageMetadata).

Comment: I think you have an extra set of closing `})`

Answer (score 0):

I have done same task by uploading video is like this:
Hope it will helps you:

```
 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child("name")
            if let uploadData = self.finalCompressedData as Data? {
                storageRef.putData(self.finalCompressedData, metadata: nil
                    , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            //                            failure(error)
                        }else{
                            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                                    // An error occurred!
                                    return
                                }
                                print(downloadURL)
                            }

                        }
                })
            }
```